# View Module Exception Strategy

Tags: zend-framework2

I have a controller that saves some data.

```
$pat = $sm->get('Tables\PaymentAttemptsTable');
$pat->save($post);
```

**The module configuration has the following config:**

```
public function onBootstrap(EventInterface $e)
{
    $em  = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $em->attach('dispatch', array($this, 'loadConfiguration' ), 100);
}

public function loadConfiguration(EventInterface $e)
{
    $sm  = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();

    //if this module
    $exceptionstrategy = $sm->get('ViewManager')->getExceptionStrategy();
    $exceptionstrategy->setExceptionTemplate('error/inserterror');
}
```

On the PaymentAttemptsTable module confi I have a similar strategy like this.

```
public function onBootstrap(EventInterface $e)
{
    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $eventManager->attach('dispatch', array($this, 'loadConfiguration' ), 100);
}

public function loadConfiguration(EventInterface $e)
{
    $sm  = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();

    //if this module
    $exceptionstrategy = $sm->get('ViewManager')->getExceptionStrategy();
    $exceptionstrategy->setExceptionTemplate('error/saveerror');
}
```

On each one I have a view confi like this.

```
return array(

'view_manager' => array(
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
    'template_map' => array(
        'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
    ),
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
```

);

**The thing is that when I do**

```
throw new SaveError('Table must be a string or instance of TableIdentifier.');
```

on the PaymentAttemptsTable class I get the template from the controller and not form the table class, is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you look at the Controller and View Models section of
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html

It shows you how to load different view templates, what you will need to do is change the view template to the one that needs to be loaded in the PaymentAttemptsTable class. This will need to be done in the calling controller.

Example from Zend.com

```
namespace Foo\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class BazBatController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function doSomethingCrazyAction()
    {
        $view = new ViewModel(array(
            'message' => 'Hello world',
        ));
        $view->setTemplate('foo/baz-bat/do-something-crazy');
        return $view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi I think this is fine for a normal view template but what I need is an Exception strategy, that when an exception rices use certain template.

Comment: Ah i see, im sorry i can't help u with that. Although if u did it in a try catch block u could apply the template change in the catch. Not a very neat way i know but im not even sure there is a built in way to achieve this.